# Webcam access in c++ without openCV

Tags: c++

Can I make some c++ webcam program without using opencv (and without others external library)? My idea is to take the data from the webcam and display it on window, like a live video. 
Could you show me some example?
Sorry for my bad english. Thank you very much.

Comment: You have to use some external library eventually, either for dealing with your webcam interface (e.g. USB, FireWire, Ethernet or other), or for dealing with decoding the format coming from the webcam and last to deal with the display issues (creating a window, resizing your image, displaying the image). OpenCV just wraps all this into one convenient framework. Please specify your restrictions or tell us why you can't use OpenCV.

Comment: @count0 well, maybe this is a homework assignment in the subjects of OS design and media processing... :D

Comment: The problem is that I can't install opencv correctly. Wich library is easier to install?

Comment: Ffmpeg should do it, but it's much harder to use it than OpenCV. If you have trouble with the installation you'll have more trouble with the use of ffmpeg. You can download prebuilt OpenCV libraries already, so installing should be no problem on Linux (ubuntu) or Windows.

Comment: Is there some program with opencv on it already?  tried codeblocks and microsoft visual c++!

Comment: You can install the OpenCV libraries pre-build for Visual Studio. You'll just need to configure it properly. Check the opencv documentation. @H2CO3 High performance video processing on embedded platforms assignment:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short: for windows and C/C++ the most straightforward way is by using the DirectShow.

There is a nice wrapper of DirectShow framegrabber here: http://www.muonics.net/school/spring05/videoInput/

Yes, you still need the DXSDK installed, but actually I managed to extract the required DShow interfaces into the single 100kb file. So my advice: live with the videoInput library.

On linux the Video4Linux(2) library is somewhat simpler. Everything is done through file-like APIs.

On MacOS X you have the [QTKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/UsingQTKit/UsingQTKit.html). To make a simple window with live camera stream is a breeze. The sample is right in the Apple's documentation.